# XSLT : Getting max value out of derived values from source XML nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML structure like below

```
<Categories>
<cat>Video</cat>
<cat>Audio</cat>
<cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

There is a mapping available for this categories in a lookup XML like this

```
<Lookup>
<cat>Video</cat>
<mapping>1</mapping>
</Lookup>
<Lookup>
<cat>Audio</cat>
<mapping>2</mapping>
</Lookup>
<Lookup>
<cat>Hybrid</cat>
<mapping>3</mapping>
</Lookup>
</ValueSet>
```

Now I am looking for an XSLT solution, which can return me the Max value as output as result of transformation without using node-set extension function.

Here are my Test cases

Test case 1 :

Input :

```
<Categories>
<cat>Video</cat>
<cat>Audio</cat>
<cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

Expected Output 3

Test case 2 :

Input :

```
<Categories>
<cat>Video</cat>
<cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

Expected Output 3

Test case 3 :

Input :

```
<Categories>
<cat>Video</cat>
<cat>Audio</cat>
</Categories>
```

Expected Output 2

Test case 4 :

Input :

```
<Categories>
<cat>Audio</cat>
<cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

Expected Output 3

Test case 5 :

Input :

```
<Categories>
<cat>Video</cat>
</Categories>
```

Expected Output 1

Thanks in advance.

**Update from comments**:

> Lookup information for me is not
>   available to load [with `document()`
>   function]. I need to do `for-each` on
>   the categories input and then derive
>   the lookup value. After that , I need
>   to get the maximum.
>
> I have an extension available from xsl
>   engine processor to get this with in
>   xslt like below:
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select='xx:lookupValue("MappingXML","Category",.,"COL1")'/>
> ```
>
> This function returns string. This
>   function doesn't return nodeset. I
>   tried with variable by capturing all
>   the derived values after executing
>   `for-each`, but to process further
>   this variable output (RTF), in XSLt
>   1.0, i have no handle on any node-set() functions.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From a comment of the OP**:

> I have an extension available from xsl
>   engine processor to get this with in
>   xslt like below : `<xsl:value-of
>   select='xx:lookupValue("MappingXML","Category",.,"COL1")'/>`
>   – satish

**This works in XSLT 2.0 and must work in XSLT 1.0** (just remove the `<xsl:function>` and use your extension function):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xx="my:xx"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xx:lookup>
    <ValueSet>
        <Lookup>
            <cat>Video</cat>
            <mapping>1</mapping>
        </Lookup>
        <Lookup>
            <cat>Audio</cat>
            <mapping>2</mapping>
        </Lookup>
        <Lookup>
            <cat>Hybrid</cat>
            <mapping>3</mapping>
        </Lookup>
    </ValueSet>
 </xx:lookup>

 <xsl:variable name="vlookupDoc" select="document('')/*/xx:lookup"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:call-template name="getMax">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="cat"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getMax">
      <xsl:param name="pcurrMax" select="-9999999999"/>
      <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>

      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
         <xsl:value-of select="$pcurrMax"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:variable name="vNewVal" select=
         "number(xx:lookupValue($vlookupDoc,$pNodes[1]))"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="getMax">
          <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() >1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pcurrMax" select=
           "number(($pcurrMax >= $vNewVal))*$pcurrMax
           +
            number(($vNewVal > $pcurrMax))*$vNewVal"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="xx:lookupValue">
      <xsl:param name="pLookupDoc"/>
      <xsl:param name="pCat"/>

      <xsl:value-of select=
        "$pLookupDoc/*/*[cat=$pCat]/mapping"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Categories>
    <cat>Video</cat>
    <cat>Audio</cat>
    <cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
3
```

**The code converted to XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="12.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xx="Your Namespace Here"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xx:lookup>
    <ValueSet>
        <Lookup>
            <cat>Video</cat>
            <mapping>1</mapping>
        </Lookup>
        <Lookup>
            <cat>Audio</cat>
            <mapping>2</mapping>
        </Lookup>
        <Lookup>
            <cat>Hybrid</cat>
            <mapping>3</mapping>
        </Lookup>
    </ValueSet>
 </xx:lookup>

 <!-- You probably don't need this and the above embedded XML -->
 <xsl:variable name="vlookupDoc" select="document('')/*/xx:lookup"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:call-template name="getMax">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="cat"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getMax">
      <xsl:param name="pcurrMax" select="-9999999999"/>
      <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>

      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
         <xsl:value-of select="$pcurrMax"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
       <!-- Change the call of the ext. function as appr. -->
         <xsl:variable name="vNewVal" select=
         "number(xx:lookupValue($vlookupDoc,$pNodes[1]))"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="getMax">
          <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() >1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pcurrMax" select=
           "($pcurrMax >= $vNewVal)*$pcurrMax
           +
            ($vNewVal > $pcurrMax)*$vNewVal"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the solution. Btw, would you please explain what thuis line does ?          <xsl:with-param name="pcurrMax" select="($pcurrMax >= $vNewVal)*$pcurrMax
           +
            ($vNewVal > $pcurrMax)*$vNewVal"/>

Comment: Hi, I am trying to filter the nodes that gets passed to template, but it is failing. what is error here ? Categories/cat[text() = 'Audio' or 'Video']. It works fine if I just have Categories/cat[text()='Audio']. Please help. I also tried Categories/cat[text() = 'Audio' or text()='Video'], but no luck.

Comment: @satish: This XPath expression returns the bigger of the two values. It uses the fact that `true()` is automatically converted in XPath 1.0 to `1` and `false()` to `0`

Comment: @satish: Use: `<xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="cat[. = 'Audio' or . = 'Video']"/> `

Comment: Thanks , this expression worked fine to filter. Sorry to ask you again , would you please elaborate more on ($pcurrMax >= $vNewVal)*$pcurrMax + ($vNewVal > $pcurrMax)*$vNewVal. Is * a multiplier ? and then why there is a +

Comment: @satish: Yes, `*` is the multiplication operator in XPath and `+` is the addition operator. The expression expresses the sum of two arguments of which exactly one is 0. The multiplication is to multiply the value with either 1 (`true()`) or 0 (`false()`)

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic maximum algorithm for XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xx="extension-URI">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Categories/cat">
            <xsl:sort select="xx:lookupValue('MappingXML',
                                             'Category',
                                             .,
                                             'COL1')"
                      data-type="number"
                      order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="xx:lookupValue('MappingXML',
                                                     'Category',
                                                     .,
                                                     'COL1')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, your restrictions and the mapping force this to add **one** extra call to the extension function... If this is a big cost, you should go with a recursive node by node (or trasversal on the following sibling axis) solution like @Dimitre.

In XPath/XSLT 2.0 it's easier:

```
max(Categories/cat/xx:lookupValue('MappingXML','Category',.,'COL1')
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It worked like charm. Is there a performance implication with this approach if I have more <cat> ? Is there a way to optimize this further from performance point of view ?

Comment: @satish: It's just one only extra call. So, the more the `cat` elements, the less performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="docLookup" select="document('lookup_file.xml')/*/Lookup"/>
        <xsl:variable name="avElms" select="cat"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$docLookup/mapping
                            [not(. &lt; ../../Lookup[cat = $avElms]/mapping)]/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results:

```
<Categories>
    <cat>Video</cat>
    <cat>Audio</cat>
    <cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

Result is `3`

```
<Categories>
    <cat>Video</cat>
    <cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

Result is `3`

```
<Categories>
    <cat>Video</cat>
    <cat>Audio</cat>
</Categories>
```

Result is `2`

```
<Categories>
    <cat>Audio</cat>
    <cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

Result is `3`

```
<Categories>
    <cat>Video</cat>
</Categories>
```

Result is `1`

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. Although , lookup information for me is not available to load the way u did here. I need to do for-each on the categories input and then derive the lookup value. After that , I need to get the maximum. Would you please modify your solution to supoort this ?

Comment: If you can't fetch via document(), how do you except to read any info from an external file? Or lookup info is in the same file?

Comment: I have an extension available from xsl engine processor to get this with in xslt like below : <xsl:value-of select='xx:lookupValue("MappingXML","Category",.,"COL1")'/>

Comment: You should have pointed this in the question. What datatype this function returns?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning in the original question. This function returns string.

Comment: So you need to match cats in Categories, for each one make a lookup via your function and when print only the max value? Any chance to get nodeset from your function?

Comment: Right, you got my requirement. This function doesn't return nodeset. I tried with variable by capturing all the derived values after executing for-each, but to process further this variable output (RTF), in XSLt 1.0, i have no handle on any node-set() functions .

Comment: I'm really falling asleep now, but if you move all these explanations to your question, you can get an answer from someone else.

Comment: thanks for your time. I will update the question. Please do check when you get some time. Good night.